# How to secure file download?

Tags: angularjs, file, security, download

I have an application written in angularjs and a dropwizard backend. All API calls are ajax, with the exception of file downloads, which is done by performing a redirect to a standard GET request.
All API calls are secured through a token which is passed as a Token header. We use SSL for all APIs.
The download GET request works but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to secure it. I have no way of setting a custom header, which is required to pass the token. So theoretically, I'm left with two options, clearly none of them acceptable: 1. Pass the token as one the GET parameters   2. Leave the download unsecured.
Any ideas how to secure file download?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting a secret token in a URL query parameter isn't great because URL tend to be leakable, for example through history/logging/referrers. There are ways to mitigate this: for example you could have the server side issue a download token that is only good for one use or for a limited amount of time. Or the client could pass a time-limited token created using a signature over the secret token that the server side could verify.

Alternatively you could, just for this one interface (eg path-limited, quitckly-expiring) put the token in a cookie.

Another approach is to download the whole file through AJAX, thus allowing you to set the header as normal. Then you have to present the content as a downloadable local resource, which requires a cocktail of browser-specific hacks (eg using data: or filesystem: URLs, and potentially links with the `download` attribute). Given the complication this isn't usually worth bothering with, especially if the file is very large which may present further storage constraints.

Comment: I like the idea of a time-limited token. The way I see it It would be valid only for a few seconds. The download call would be preceded with a GetDownloadToken call, which would be protected by a regular token.